# Controlling menu item state in a Chrome / Firefox extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

My web extension for Chrome and Firefox needs to control the checked state of context menu items it creates. This works in current Firefox (57, on Windows), but Chrome (64) appears to take over complete control. In Chrome, the checked state of a menu item gets toggled as user clicks it, but setting the checked state from my add-on code has no effect.

I narrowed it down to the following example (background page, with "contextMenus" permission):

```
// prepare a bunch of menu items...
const items = [];
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
    items.push(`test-item-${i}`)
}
// ...they will all change state in sync...
let allChecked = true;
// ...create the menu
buildContextMenuItems();

// now clicking any item should check / uncheck all items.
// Works in Firefox, does not work in Chrome.

function buildContextMenuItems() {
    for (let item of items) {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            id: item,
            title: item,
            contexts: ['all'],
            onclick: handleItemClick,
            type: 'checkbox',
            checked: allChecked // initially: true
        });
    }
}

function handleItemClick(info, tab) {
    allChecked = !allChecked;
    console.log('wait a bit before seeing if it worked!')
    // use setTimeout in case the browser needs time to update menu state
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('toggling all items to', allChecked);
        for (let item of items) {
            chrome.contextMenus.update(item, {checked: allChecked});
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

In short, after chrome.contextMenus.update(), the checked state is as expected in Firefox, while in Chrome only the item actually clicked toggles state. (No amount of waiting in setTimeout makes any difference).

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: https://crbug.com/791671 - it's a bug in Chrome 62.0.3172.0, fixed in 65.0.3289.0. Simply check navigator.userAgent, parse the build number, and in the affected version range use a fallback: remove the item, add it with the new state.

Comment: Thanks! If you post it as an answer, I will close the question.